# Value for html control always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I know I have a similar question but I selected a answer as correct before I actually tested it since technically they were correct I was trying to use .text.

I have html control and im trying to get the input value from the user however for some reason even though I have data when I debug that line it just shows ""

```
<input runat="server" id="Name" type="text" name="Name"/>

cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@NAME", Name.value);
```

name.value never has a value no matter what I put in the input name control.

Comment: What did you mean with "name.value" as parameter's value? Aren't you trying to get `Name` control value? If this is the case, you need `Name.Value`

Comment: Why is it `"name.value"` and not `Name.Value`?

Comment: you could just use `<asp:Textbox id="Name"...>` and then get the `.Text` property of this control?

Comment: You can edit a question and un-accept an answer.

Comment: Sorry Henk was not aware that you could un-accept the answer will know for next time

Comment: Did you catch that one yourself Yuck or did the first line of this question give it away?

Comment: @Henry Please do not edit the content out of your question. The community will take care of removing it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes:

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@name", name.value);
```

You are literally passing "name.value" instead of the value property.

Comment: sorry that was a typo there are no quotes in the code

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input runat="server" id="Name" type="text" name="Name"/>

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", name.value));
```

Comment: This does not work either once the debugger gets to that line it shows name.value = "" when I know I added a value

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<input runat="server" id="Name" type="text" name="Name"/>

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", Request.Form["Name"]));
```